# ASP.NET MVC 3 fetch the database from Web site Administration tool

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to fetch user data from web site administration tool for managing users in my application. Is it possible to set table in SQL Server 2008 by using Model? 
I want to display the user information in table. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of using the Membership API is that you access the data via the API.  This abstracts the Membership system from the physical implementation, so the implementation can change without your app caring.

If you want the list of users, then do this:

```
var users = Membership.GetAllUsers();
```

Users is a MembershipUserCollection, which you can then use to access the data and populate your UI.